# useInfiniteQuery doesn't keep previous data (react-query)

Tags: reactjs, pagination, next.js, infinite-scroll, react-query

I'm trying to implement useInfiniteQuery for pagination scroll with filters for a backend that doesn't support pagination cursor (I'm using limit and start parameters).
I was able to retrieve my data but my hasNextPage variable is always undefined. I cannot fetch more data. When the button is used to trigger fetchNextPage, new data can be seen but it removes the previous data.

[image: console]

What am I doing wrong ? Here is my code:

```
// Query data
  const { 
      data, 
      status, 
      error, 
      isSuccess, 
      hasNextPage,
      fetchNextPage, 
      isFetching,
      isFetchingNextPage, 
      isLoading,
      isError,
  } = useInfiniteQuery(
    [
      'vendors',
      {vendor_type: vendorTypesId}, 
      {country: countryId}, 
      {city: cityId}, 
      {vendor_product_types: productCategoryId}, 
      {page: thisPage}, 
      {start: start}, 
      {name: nameInput},
      {limit: limit},
    ],
    getVendors, 
   { 
      initialData: {
        pages : [{
          result: vendors,
          resultCount: 495,
          pageId: 0,
          nextPageId: 15
        }], 
        pageParams: startParams
      }
    },
    {getNextPageParam: (lastPage, pages) => lastPage.nextPageId}
    {keepPreviousData: true}
  )
```

**Update:**
hasNextPage was always undefined beacause *getNextPageParam* and *initialData* were in two separated objects. I corrected it like this :

```
{ 
      initialData: {
        pages : [{
          result: vendors,
          resultCount: 495,
          pageId: 0,
          nextPageId: 15
        }], 
        pageParams: startParams
      },
    
       getNextPageParam: (lastPage, pages) => lastPage.nextPageId
}
```

It now returns true but clicking on the button still erase the previous data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have the same problem as described in your `update`: react-query only takes *one* options object, where you should put all options like `initialData`, `getNextPageParam` and `keepPreviousData`, so something like:

```
useInfiniteQuery(
  'key',
  queryFn,
  {
    initialData: {...},
    getNextPageParam: () => ...,
    keepPreviousData: true,
  }
)
```

also, please be aware that `initialData` is also applied when the query key changes, because a new cache entry is created. So by supplying `initialData`, `keepPreviousData` might become irrelevant because the previous data is only shown *until* you have correct data for your new query key. And since `initialData` is persisted to the cache, it is treated as a valid response for the new query key.

if you only want to apply `initialData` to a specific query key (like the one that you show initially, where not filters are applied), you need to make sure of that yourselves: Set `initialData` to `undefined` for all keys where you don't want initial data, and set it to something for all the keys where you want it.

Comment: Thank you, this has gave me a better insight. I wasn't sure on how to operate your recommandation so to avoid confusion between "initialData" and new queries data, I simply replaced "getNextPageParam: (lastPage, pages) => lastPage.nextPageId" by "(lastPage, pages) => pages.length * limit" and it now seems to work...!